# Getting font from CFontDialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm creating a simple GUI for changing the input text formatting in Visual C++ and would like to know how to fetch font type from CFontDialog.

Input text is fetched from EditBox to the m_txtEdit and then passed to m_text.

```
void CTxtDlg::OnOK()
{

    m_txtEdit.GetWindowText(m_text);
    CDialog::OnOK();
}
```

m_text is a member of a CDoc class and should be formatted according to what the user selects in the CFontDialog.

The selected font is passed to the LOGFONT m_lf variable which is a member of CTxtDlg class.

The CFont m_font should be made equal to LOGFONT m_lf.

```
void CTxtDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{


    CFontDialog dlg;
    int response = dlg.DoModal();                         
    dlg.GetCurrentFont(&m_lf);
}
```

The CView class should output the CString m_text formatted according to what is set in CFont m_font.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Google "cfontdialog example".

Comment: Completely unclear question. I have no idea, why you are talking about retrieving text from an Edit control. That seems totally unrelated to your question. But we don't even know, what your question is. You are talking about getting a *"font type"* into a variable called `m_font`, but never even explain, what type it is. And then you show code that uses a different variable (`m_lf`). Please fix this question. As currently asked, it should be closed.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41717311/edit) your question. Don't just add information as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your question is completely unrelated to the `CFontDialog`. [Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717311/getting-font-from-cfontdialog#comment70637134_41717311) is asking, how to create a [CFont](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stebcezc.aspx) object given a [LOGFONT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037.aspx) structure. That's what the [CFont::CreateFontIndirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stebcezc.aspx#cfont__createfontindirect) member function is for:

```
if ( !m_font.CreateFontIndirect( &m_lf ) ) {
    // handle error
}
// use m_font
```

Comment: @Marko: I don't know, how `CTxtDlg` and `CDoc` are related, or even what types they are. If `CTxtDlg` is `CView`-derived and `CDoc` is `CDocument`-derived, you can call [CView::GetDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezc3635w.aspx#cview__getdocument) from `CTxtDlg`, perform an appropriate cast to the returned pointer, and access `m_font` from there. Although I have no idea, why a `CFont` object ended up in the document in the first place. Sounds like pretty rough class design (or lack thereof rather).

Answer (score 0):

First add a `CFont` to your `CTxtDlg`:

```
class CTxtDlg {
    ....
    CFont m_font;
}
```

Then create and use the font:

```
void CTxtDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CFontDialog dlg;
    int response = dlg.DoModal();
    if(response == IDOK) {
        dlg.GetCurrentFont(&m_lf);
        VERIFY(m_font.CreateFontIndirect(&m_lf));
        SetFont(&m_font);
    }
}
```

Please note that as far as I understand it the font must remain valid after SetFont, so you cannot easily destroy the font and recreate it if it is still set in the dialog.